# Routing Asp.Net AngularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having a porblem with the ng-view which doesn't want to load.
If I press on a link I get the following Url:
http://localhost:63024/Home/Index#/routeOne

**Code for my controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult One()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Two()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Three()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So a very simple Controller.

**And the following routing:**

```
var configFunction = function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/routeOne', {
        templateUrl: 'Home/one'
    })
    .when('/routeTwo', {
        templateUrl: 'Home/two'
    })
    .when('/routeThree', {
        templateUrl: 'Home/three'
    });
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

myApp.config(configFunction);
```

**And the following view:**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#/routeOne">Route One</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/routeTwo">Route Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/routeThree">Route Three</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: You are mixing Angular routing (client side) with ASP.net routing (server side) - they aren't the same... typically you would use Angular routing to "navigate" to views without involving server routing (Angular will obtain a new view/template via Ajax/XHR)

Comment: So I should provide only one routing engine, either the Angular routing or the Asp.net routing?

Comment: Or can I combine Angular routing with Asp.net routing?

Comment: I don't want to say Angular is _only_ for SPA (single page applications), because it is not, however, that is where it shines. I will also not say you can't mix server and client side when using Angular because you _can_ (I do). It _depends_ on what you are trying to accomplish - e.g. the famous "todo app" Angular tutorial could just be one part of your web site, where Angular does all the _"todo application"_ processes/routing in a single "page" via AJAX/XHR (but the "page" itself in is an ASP.net view that a user navigated to from other parts of your web site via ASP.net routing). Hth....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you specified views for those controller actions in the mvc app, and ng-controller / ng-app on the angular side? (posting this as answer as i can't post a comment)